# 301 redirect sub page

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect 
http://www.polisheddiamonds.co.nz/blog/category4
 to 
http://www.polisheddiamonds.co.nz/blog

but the site has html pages and they already works using htaccess redirection

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^blog(.*)$ /blog.html?page=$1 [L]
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: What is the purpose of redirecting `http://www.polisheddiamonds.co.nz/blog/category4 to http://www.polisheddiamonds.co.nz/blog`

Comment: there is no purpose... i want jsut when user click on this http://www.polisheddiamonds.co.nz/blog/category4 it should be redirected to http://www.polisheddiamonds.co.nz/blog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^blog/category4/?$ /blog? [L,NC,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^blog(.*)$ /blog.html?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: same problem again
 want to redirect http://www.polisheddiamonds.com.au/diamond-rings/cushion-diamond-ring-spaf01-240.html to http://www.polisheddiamonds.com.au/diamond-rings

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^diamond-rings(.*)$ /diamond-rings.html?diamond-rings=/diamond-rings/$1 [L]

Comment: Your target URL `http://www.polisheddiamonds.com.au/diamond-rings/cushion-diamond-ring-spaf01-240.html` is not matching with your rule. I would suggest creating a new question an describe your problem in detail.